# Трудности с DockPanel - не работает выравнивание

Tags: c#, wpf

```
   <DockPanel  Width="Auto" Height="Auto">

        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="50">dock 2.1</Button>


    </DockPanel>
```

- вот в таком случае получается, что кнопка находится по центру а не справа

но, если добавить вот так

```
 <DockPanel Name="DP1">

        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="50">dock 2.1</Button>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="50">dock 2.1</Button>



    </DockPanel>
```

- то уже вторая кнопка будет "примагничиваться" - правильно, а первая так и будет по центру.
Как сделать - что бы первая кнопка(она у меня должна быть одна)  сразу была справа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте свойство `LastChildFill`:

```
<DockPanel  LastChildFill="False">
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="50">dock 2.1</Button>
</DockPanel>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> Такой эффект получается благодаря установке у DockPanel свойства
>   LastChildFill="True", которое означает, что последний элемент
>   заполняет все оставшееся место. Если у этого свойства поменять True на
>   False, то кнопка прижмется к левой стороне, заполнив только о место,
>   которое ей необходимо.

[Здесь можете почитать о `DockPanel`.](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/4.5.php)